# When to use query and params to get url data in express

Tags: node.js, url, express, routes, url-parameters

It seems that `/patient/123` and `/patient?id=123` will both work fine at the backend of my application.

I could do `req.param.id` and do `req.query.id` as well.

But I'm getting confused on when to use then. What are the cases that you should use **params** and what are the cases that you should use **query**. Because in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15400574/2889614), [j_mcnally](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1052788/j-mcnally) only mentioned that they're interchangeable.

> Url params and url path are somewhat interchangeable. People usually use url path for describing restful resources...

So what are the possible **pros** and **cons** of using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query string is usually *modifiers* to the resource you're running, while the path should give just enough info to let your back-end indentify the data you're requesting.

`/patients/123` - `patients` in this case would be the *namespace*, and `123` would be the *identifier*. You can also extend this with:
`/patients/123/profile` where `profile` would be an *identifier* for a *pre-defined collection of data*.

Query string usually offers fine-grained control over what and how your resource presents data, for example:

`/patients/123?fields=firstname,lastname,age` - This is pretty self-explanatory, but basically the query string in this case modifies *what* data is returned.
`/patients?orderby=age&order=desc&fields=firstname,lastname&limit=25` - This query string modifies both *how* and *what* data is returned, and that's the purpose of the query string in RESTful API's.

Comment: Great answer! Now it makes sense. Thank you so much. :)