# How to add a query param to the url with hash?

Tags: javascript, url

I have an URL string: `http:/some.other.com/#/app/`.

I want to make it a string with a certain query param: `http:/some.other.com/#/app/?my-param=whatever`

I tried to do it like this:

```
function addQueryParam(url, key, value) {
  const newUrl = new URL(url)
  newUrl.searchParams.set(key, value)
  return newUrl.toString()
}

addQueryParam('http:/some.other.com/#/app/', 'my-param', 'whatever')
```

I expected to have following URL:

```
http:/some.other.com/#/app/?my-param=whatever
```

But the result is:

```
http://some.other.com/?my-param=whatever#/app/
```

Maybe I missed something, but I guess a lot of apps such as angular, vue and I guess react use hash in the middle of the url string. So how to add query params properly in that case?

Comment: Actually, you need to modify the `URL`'s [`hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/hash)... Regarding how the URL is serialized, see [the spec](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-url-serializer). The `#` and everything after is the hash, and is appended to the end of the URL.

Comment: That's because hash/fragment always comes after the query string: the URL you want to achieve is actually invalid. In fact, with your proposed URL the server will never be able to read the query string, because it is considered part of the hash. Your JS code is actually generating the **correct URL**.

Comment: Terry is right. Take a look at [`URI § Generic Syntax` on the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax)

Comment: You might want to read [Hash params vs url params, when to use which?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15238391/215552)

Comment: Wouldn't matter if he's not sending the request to the server. Perhaps he is using the hash to work around using the history API while still using a SPA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments are partially right, this information will not make it to the server. However, if you're just doing client-side logic then nothing is stopping you. Below is an example of how to achieve what you're looking for.

```js
function addHashQueryParam(url, key, value) {
  const existing = (url.lastIndexOf('?') > url.lastIndexOf('#')) ?
    url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('?') + 1) : '';
    
  const query = new URLSearchParams(existing);
  query.set(key, value)
  return `${url.replace(`?${existing}`, '')}?${query.toString()}`;
}

let url = 'http:/some.other.com/#/app/';

url = addHashQueryParam(url, 'my-param', 'whatever');
console.log(url)

url = addHashQueryParam(url, 'my-second-param', 'whomever');
console.log(url)
```